# Why is GNU Indent doing what it seems to be a self rule violation?

Tags: text-formatting, indentation

I'm using **GNU Indent** to format some code. I have some lines like this one:

```
port->N[0].BTR.U = (DIV8(0U)    |
                    TSEG2(0x3U) |
                    TSEG1(0xEU) |
                    SJW(0x3U)   |
                    BRP(0x9U));
```

That are being formatted to code like this:

```
port->N[0].BTR.U = (DIV8(0U) | TSEG2(0x3U) | TSEG1(0xEU) | SJW(0x3U) | BRP(0x9U));
```

I am using the `-l80` option that, according to the documentation, should break the line at 80 characters. Here the code was originally shorter than that but after the formatting, the resulting line is beyond the 80 characters! So how is indent violating it's own rule? Also as far as I understand I didn't specify any option for doing this, I mean, taking code from several lines and place it in one single line.

And this is really annoying because I don't want this to be modified. So, does anybody know what command or combination of commands can I use to avoid this?

These are the options I'm already using:

```
-ndj -nbad -bap -nbc -nbbo -hnl -bl -bli0 -bls -blf -ncdb -nce -cp1 
-ncs -di2 -nfc1 -nfca -hnl -i4 -ip0 -lp -npcs -nprs -psl -saf -sai 
-saw -nsc -nsob -cli4 -cbi0 -nut -nbs -npsl -l80 -c90 -cd90
```

Regards!

Comment: Can't reproduce. My version of `indent` (GNU 2.2.9) adds a line break after `DIV8(0U) |`.

Comment: Also not reproducable with GNU indent 2.2.11.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing hiding in your `~/.indent.pro`?

Comment: @ThomasErker; I'm not using a .pro file. I'm specifying the commands directly when calling indent.

Comment: Quick thought, can you step through each of the options listed and state how those options would alter the given line? http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html#SEC12 has some remarks on how some of your options might apply.

Comment: I've tried all combinations of the commands mentioned in that section, I think I don't get what you mean.

Comment: What version of `ident` on what system are you using? Also run `strace -eread ident` to confirm that it does not use some (global?) config.

Comment: @ThomasErker: I'm using Indent 2.2.10 on windows.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in 2.2.10 or in your binary. Can you get an updated binary? If you were having problems on Linux/Unix, I would say get the source and compile it yourself (`ident` has *no* dependencies), but on your environment that might be more complicated. Really don't know.